# Removing brackets around listed elements on VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

I have a VisualForce page with an extension that returns data from a list. When the data is displayed on the page, it appears as:

[A, B, C, D, E, F]

Is there any way to get rid of the brackets on each side so that it appears as:

A, B, C, D, E, F

Here is the code for my extension constructor.

```
List<String> myList {get; set;}
public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con)
{
    this.myList = new List<String>{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
}
```

So when I display it on my VisualForce page with {!myList}, the brackets show up. I still want them all on the same line separated by commas (not iterated through). Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy....

```
List<String> myList {get; set;}
public String myListString {get;set;};

public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con)
{
    this.myList = new List<String>{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    myListStirng = string.join(myList,',');
}
```

Then output myListString on the page